# Kafka JDBC Connect query causes ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have this Oracle SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT SO_ORDER_KEY,QUEUE_TYPE,SYS_NO,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SO_ORDER_KEY ORDER BY SYS_NO DESC) ORDER_RANK 
    FROM TSY940) 
WHERE ORDER_RANK=1;
```

When running in SQL developer, it returns the desired result.

For some reason when I use this query in the kafka-connect-jdbc properties I get

```
ERROR Failed to run query for table TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{name='null', query='SELECT * FROM (SELECT SO_ORDER_KEY,QUEUE_TYPE,SYS_NO,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SO_ORDER_KEY ORDER BY SYS_NO DESC) ORDER_RANK FROM TSY940) WHERE ORDER_RANK=1', topicPrefix='TSY940', timestampColumn='SYS_NO', incrementingColumn='null'}: {} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:247)
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:774)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4845)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1501)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.executeQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:201)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TableQuerier.java:84)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:55)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask.poll(JdbcSourceTask.java:225)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:179)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here is my properties file:

```
name=poc-oracle-source
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.password = ********
connection.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@***.***.***.**:****/******
connection.user = ***********
table.types=TABLE
query=SELECT * FROM (SELECT SO_ORDER_KEY,QUEUE_TYPE,SYS_NO,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SO_ORDER_KEY ORDER BY SYS_NO DESC) ORDER_RANK FROM TSY940) WHERE ORDER_RANK=1
mode=timestamp
timestamp.column.name=SYS_NO
topic.prefix=TSY940
batch.max.rows = 500
poll.interval.ms=60000

transforms=createKey,extract
transforms.createKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.createKey.fields=SO_ORDER_KEY
transforms.extract.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.extract.field=SO_ORDER_KEY
```

I use the ojdbc7 driver.

The WHERE clause seams to be the issue because I don't get the exception when I replace the query property with

```
query=SELECT * FROM (SELECT SO_ORDER_KEY,QUEUE_TYPE,SYS_NO,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SO_ORDER_KEY ORDER BY SYS_NO DESC) ORDER_RANK FROM TSY940)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may then try this query which completely eliminates the `ORDER_RANK`

```
SELECT SO_ORDER_KEY, QUEUE_TYPE, SYS_NO
FROM (
 SELECT SO_ORDER_KEY, QUEUE_TYPE, SYS_NO 
 FROM (SELECT SO_ORDER_KEY, QUEUE_TYPE, SYS_NO,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY SO_ORDER_KEY ORDER BY SYS_NO DESC) AS ORDER_RANK 
      FROM TSY940) sub
 WHERE sub.ORDER_RANK=1
)
```

The best way to see what is causing the problem is to enable 10046 trace and see the exact query that is send to database and that is causing the `ORA-00933`.

Comment: Wraping the query in another SELECT does the trick as a workaround. I don't have enough permission to enable the 10046 trace at the moment but the workaround will do trick for the sake of my poc. Here's the query I use:
SELECT * FROM (SELECT SO_ORDER_KEY,QUEUE_TYPE,SYS_NO FROM (SELECT SO_ORDER_KEY,QUEUE_TYPE,SYS_NO,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY SO_ORDER_KEY ORDER BY SYS_NO DESC) AS ORDER_RANK FROM TSY940) WHERE ORDER_RANK=1)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has an accepted answer, but the problem you were having (and why wrapping the query in another query solved the issue) is that when a Connect job is running in `timestamp` mode, Connect appends a clause to the query using the specified timestamp field. What that means is that Connect was passing this invalid query to Oracle:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT
            SO_ORDER_KEY,
            QUEUE_TYPE,
            SYS_NO,
            DENSE_RANK()
            OVER (
              PARTITION BY SO_ORDER_KEY
              ORDER BY SYS_NO DESC ) ORDER_RANK
          FROM TSY940)
    WHERE ORDER_RANK = 1
    WHERE SYS_NO >= {last_run_timestamp}
```

See the last line? That was being added by Connect. When you wrap your query in another `SELECT`, that appended clause no longer causes a problem.

When I first had this problem, I found no mention of it anywhere in the documentation, and it was pretty irritating.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add aliases and remove `TO_CHAR`:

```
SELECT SO_ORDER_KEY, QUEUE_TYPE, SYS_NO 
FROM (SELECT SO_ORDER_KEY, QUEUE_TYPE, SYS_NO,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY SO_ORDER_KEY ORDER BY SYS_NO DESC) AS ORDER_RANK 
      FROM TSY940) sub
WHERE sub.ORDER_RANK=1;
```

Comment: It still throws the exception. The TO_CHAR slipped in while I was debugging but was not intended initially. I edited it.
ERROR Failed to run query for table TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{name='null', query='SELECT * FROM (SELECT SO_ORDER_KEY,QUEUE_TYPE,SYS_NO,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SO_ORDER_KEY ORDER BY SYS_NO DESC) ORDER_RANK FROM TSY940) sub WHERE sub.ORDER_RANK=1', topicPrefix='TSY940', timestampColumn='SYS_NO', incrementingColumn='null'}: {} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:247)
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @Alex Please replace `*` with columns names to avoid returning ORDER_RANK which does not belong to TSY940 table

Comment: I tried it before posting but here I combined it with the use of aliases. Still throws the error.
ERROR Failed to run query for table TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{name='null', query='SELECT SO_ORDER_KEY,QUEUE_TYPE,SYS_NO FROM (SELECT SO_ORDER_KEY,QUEUE_TYPE,SYS_NO,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SO_ORDER_KEY ORDER BY SYS_NO DESC) ORDER_RANK FROM TSY940) sub WHERE sub.ORDER_RANK=1', topicPrefix='TSY940', timestampColumn='SYS_NO', incrementingColumn='null'}: {} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:247)

Answer (score 0):

Fails because connector appends its timestamp clause. One can possibly use one's query with predicate as inner query, something like this : "select * from (select a,b,c from table where a='x'). This works as a workaround, as Alex mentioned. Please find the issue here:https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/566