# confluent - kafka-connect - JDBC source connector - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I've the following sql query in my kafka jdbc source connector properties file :

```
query=SELECT * FROM JENNY.WORKFLOW where ID = '565231'
```

If I run the same query in sql developer, it works fine and fetching the results. But if I use the same query in the "jdbc_workflow_connect.properties", getting the following error :

```
(io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTaskConfig:223)
[2018-09-19 12:32:15,130] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=Workflow-DB-source-0} 
Source task finished initialization and start 
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:158)
[2018-09-19 12:32:15,328] ERROR Failed to run query for table 
TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{name='null', query='SELECT * FROM 
JENNY.WORKFLOW where ID = '565231'', topicPrefix='workflow_data1', 
timestampColumn='null', incrementingColumn='ID'}: {} 
(io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:247)
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:776)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3867)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1502)
at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.executeQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:201)
at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TableQuerier.java:84)
at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:55)
at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask.poll(JdbcSourceTask.java:225)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:179)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
```

Here is my JDBC source connector properties file content :

```
name=Workflow-DB-source
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.password = ******
connection.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.1.1.1:****/****
connection.user = *****
table.types=TABLE
query=SELECT * FROM JENNY.WORKFLOW where ID = '565231'

mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=ID
topic.prefix=workflow_data1
timestamp.delay.interval.ms=60000

transforms:createKey
transforms.createKey.type:org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.createKey.fields:ID
```

I'm using ojdbc7.jar

Observation :

If I remove the "WHERE" clause, the query is working fine(like below) :

```
SELECT * FROM JENNY.WORKFLOW
```

Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong or any modifications required for setting in the jdbc source connector.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove single quotes arround the id if it is a numeric column

Comment: Removed the single quotes around the "ID", but still same error

Comment: I think you'd better adding more quotes :`'SELECT * FROM 
JENNY.WORKFLOW where ID = ''565231'''`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, didn't work. Getting this error "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement". Following is the error : `[2018-09-19 13:28:45,446] ERROR Failed to run query for table TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{name='null', query=''SELECT * FROM JENNY.WORKFLOW where ID = ''565231'''', topicPrefix='eoc_device_data1', timestampColumn='null', incrementingColumn='ID'}: {} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:247)
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
`

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48749962/kafka-jdbc-connect-query-causes-ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of the [JDBC Connect Configuration options](https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/configuration_options.html) you may read

> If specified, the query to perform to select new or updated rows. Use this setting if you want to join tables, select subsets of columns in a table, or filter data. If used, this connector will only copy data using this query – whole-table copying will be disabled. Different query modes may still be used for incremental updates, but in order to properly construct the incremental query, it must be possible to append a WHERE clause to this query (i.e. no WHERE clauses may be used).

So if you realy want to consider only the part of the table with a given `ID` you must wrap the query as follows

```
 select * from (SELECT * FROM JENNY.WORKFLOW where ID = '565231')
```

But please be sure you checked the documentation of the *Configuration Options* and you know the role of the `query` parameter.